# Read a Oracle BLOB written in little endian using C++

Tags: c++, c, .net, oracle, blob

I have a Oracle table with BLOB Column that is visible from a application build in .NET. i am not able to extract the BLOB column as it is written in little endian.

I tried to extract the BLOB via Oracle Code with below code but not able to do so.

Not working:

select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(BLOB_FIELD)) from TABLE_WITH_BLOB where ID = '';

How to extract a BLOB which is written in c++ , stores the blob data in little endian ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results in pl/sql? What doe "not working" mean?

Comment: The output looks like below when i run the query i mentioned in the post:     "&"

Comment: The data is coming a encrypted when using the query ......